# Angularjs reset all forms in a page to pristine state

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have a search button in Angularjs application, when i click search button that will render different widgets each widget have `<form>` that submit data to the server if any one form validation fails and the state of the form is $dirty. if I search again with different values and wants to clear the previous errors.

How can i reset all the forms to $pristine on clicking search button again?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$scope.formName.$setPristine(true)`. This is available in later versions of angular and is used to reset the forms to pristine state

Comment: I have multiple forms in page and want to reset all the forms in single click.

Comment: Add this method call for all the forms by giving them form names

Comment: think practically i have  more than 10 forms in a page i cannot do that each and every form.

Comment: I've multi step form where fields are distributed on 6 different states with ui-router. I want to reset form data on submit of last state after posting response to API. Tried different approaches e.g `$setPristine` or `form.data = {}` or `form.data = []`. But no luck so far. Any help would be highly appreciable.

AngularJS version is 1.7x.