# Angular get deep copy using web service

Tags: angularjs, deep-copy

I am newly developer in angular, i create sample code using json object, how to get angular.copy using web services. help me.

**Code**

```
$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"js/"+ $stateParams.id +".json",
        data:'JSON',
    }).then(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        $scope.geteditlist = response.data;
        $scope.isEditlist = true;
        //console.log($scope.geteditlist);
    })
```

Comment: for what purpose you want to use angular.copy? please elaborate

Comment: I just want to be able to hit the reset button and put my original values back. Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Store the original list in a variable. Why would you need deep copy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs reset all forms in a page to pristine state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356679/angularjs-reset-all-forms-in-a-page-to-pristine-state)